# How do i sort lists lexicographically

Tags: python, sorting, plot

i am doing a physics project and i want to plot something. i'm taking the mean out of every file and i want to plot those means. To read those files in, I used glob, this screwed up the whole order of my data tho. And when i try to use "sorted" it doesn't work the way. Here is my code:

```
#importeren van libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import glob

#definieren van de lijsten
i = 0
R1 = []
I1 = []
U1 = []
stdI = []
stdU = []

lijst = glob.glob('*.txt')
lijst = sorted(lijst)
#loop aanmaken
for i in lijst:
    try:
#        data inlezen
        data = pd.read_csv(i, skiprows=5, delimiter='\t',
                   names=['Time', 'Voltage', 'Current'], decimal=',')
    except:
        print('fout gegaan bij',i )

#   kolommen definieren  
    t = data['Time']
    U = data['Voltage']
    I = data['Current']

    Ug = np.mean(U)
    stdUg = np.std(U)
    Ig = np.mean(I)
    stdIg = np.std(I)
    R = (Ug / Ig)
    R1.append(R)
    stdI.append(stdIg)
    stdU.append(stdUg)
    I1.append(Ig)
    U1.append(Ug)


R1 = np.array(R1)
stdI = np.array(stdI)
stdU = np.array(stdU)
Irel = (stdI/Ig)
Urel = (stdU/Ug)
stdR = R*(Irel+Urel)
```

the way it gets sorted is:

```
'0A.txt',
 '10A.txt',
 '11A.txt',
 '12A.txt',
 '13A.txt',
 '14A.txt',
 '15A.txt',
 '16A.txt',
 '17A.txt',
 '18A.txt',
 '19A.txt',
 '1A.txt',
 '20A.txt',
 '21A.txt',
 '22A.txt',
```

instead of from 1-22

Comment: It's sorted alphabetically (by char code). [Custom Python list sorting](//stackoverflow.com/q/11850425)

Comment: Yeah i understand that, but how do i fix it?

Comment: You can try `lijst  = sorted(lijst, key=lambda x: int(re.sub("[^0-9]","", x)))` This does a custom sort removing all non-digit chars from the name. You need to `import re`.

Comment: yes thank you it worked! Could u explain what it all ment and what every part did? i want to understand more of programming. cuz otherwise i just keep copypasting from old files without knowing what it does haha.

Comment: i want to ask one more questing, i want to plot it now, but i want to use just the number part of the list "lijst" how do i do that? i can't do n = range(66) (66 is the length of the list) because the list stops at 50A.txt and goes to 300A.txt

Comment: I'll type up an answer. Warning: I'm a C++ programmer who dabbles in Python. There may be a more "Pythonic" solution but my methods work.

Comment: BTW `glob` doesn't mess up anything. With files from the filesystem there is no guaranteed order anyway. So you can't even rely on getting the names sorted in lexicographic order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sorted` function takes a few optional arguments. One of these is "key" which *"specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element"*. So you can use that function to convert the file name to a number and return that number. I use Regular Expressions to do that:

```
lijst = sorted(lijst, key=lambda x: int(re.sub("[^0-9]","", x)))
```

The function takes the argument `x`, strips all non-digits, and returns an integer. For example: `"1A.txt"` -> `1`. This returns

```
['0A.txt', '1A.txt', '10A.txt', '11A.txt', '12A.txt', '13A.txt', '14A.txt', '15A.txt', '16A.txt', '17A.txt', '18A.txt', '19A.txt', '20A.txt', '21A.txt', '22A.txt']
```

You can use a similar technique to map each file name in the list to a number:

```
lijst= list(map(lambda x: int(re.sub("[^0-9]","", x)), lijst))
```

The return value from the `map` function is converted to a list. This returns

```
[0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
```